# Web Deployment Issue Using Windows Azure Accelerator For WebRoles

Tags: msdeploy

I am new to Azure Accelerator for web roles I have performed each step on the guidance from the net but I am getting an error when I try to deploy my website.Everything is rechecked by me WMSvc is running and is set to auto and username and password is correct but I dont understand where is the problem.

Error 1 Web deployment task failed.(Remote agent (URL http://2f96c9ab6cda4281bcf25a899d66955d.cloudapp.net/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted. Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.) Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator. Error details: Remote agent (URL http://2f96c9ab6cda4281bcf25a899d66955d.cloudapp.net/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted. Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer. An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 0 0 QuickMVCdep

Please help me to find the solution so that I can deliver my project to Client.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue.

It appears that the Publish action from the VS Azure tools will set up the MSDeploy correctly as part of the deployment process, but creating a package from VS and then upgrading the server using the Azure portal will not.  Which is a bummer since the VS Publish action deletes the deployment and then recreates it, which will reassign your VIP address.

I haven't been able to pinpoint the difference, but one thing I've noticed is that if you do a Publish from VS, MS Web Deploy 2.0 will be installed for you, whereas I don't believe it is when you run an Upgrade.  That said, I've never managed to manually install/configure the right bits on an Azure server to enable MSDeploy (I suspect that there is some LB/firewall configuration that happens outside of the host to allow traffic to 8172).

All in all, MSDeploy is useful enough during development that I prefer that pain (which requires me to change my A record in my DNS every time I do a major upgrade) over the alternative (Upgrade using the portal and lose the ability to use MSDeploy).

I would love to learn of a solution where we can have our cake and eat it too (an upgrade package that allows MSDeploy'ing a web role).